# ExtJS 5: Get initialConfig of defined class

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to get the `initialConfig` of a class that I have defined and used in a panel. By initial config, I mean I want what was set when using the class in the panel, as well as what the class's defined values are. Here's an example:

```
Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
  alias: 'viewmodel.myview',
  stores: {
    gridStore: {
      autoLoad: true,
      fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'userval', 'doj'],
      proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',
        reader: {
          type: 'json'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

Ext.define('MyGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  xtype: 'myGrid',
  viewModel: {
    type: 'myview'
  },
  title: 'Simpsons',
  stateful: true,
  multiSelect: true,
  stateId: 'stateGrid',
  closable: true,
  bind: {
    store: '{gridStore}'
  },
  columns: [{
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    stateId: 'name'
  }, {
    text: 'Email',
    dataIndex: 'email',
    flex: 1,
    stateId: 'email'
  }, {
    text: 'Phone',
    dataIndex: 'phone',
    stateId: 'phone'
  }, {
    text: 'Date of Joining',
    dataIndex: 'doj',
    flex: 1,
    stateId: 'date'
  }]
});
Ext.define('MyController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.myview'
});
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider'));
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  title: 'My Panel',
  controller: 'myview',
  height: 400,
  width: 400,
  layout: 'fit',
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  items: [{
    xtype: 'myGrid',
    reference: 'something'
  }],
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(panel) {
      console.log(panel.lookupReference('something').initialConfig);
    }
  }
});
```

And what gets outputted:

```
Object {
  xtype="myGrid",
  reference="something"
}
```

So in the `afterrender` handler, when I output `initialConfig`, I would like to see what was set up in the panel's config for my class, as well as the class's defined properties, like columns, title, etc. I've tried looking at `config`, but that doesn't give me the columns... I realize I can look at the grid's columns directly, but if the user changes something to one of them (hides/reorders), I don't want those changes. Is there some other property that I can look to for this?

Comment: Why would you want this? What is the user case?

Comment: It basically comes down to me having stateful true on the grid, and a Revert Grid Preferences button in the toolbar... when the user clicks that, I want to revert the grid to its original, non-preference state.  I make use of `reconfigure` to perform this action, which works on other grids that aren't defined like I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the state and reconfigure the grid with the columns of the prototype:

```
var grid = panel.lookupReference('something'),
    store = grid.getStore();

// Clear the state of the grid
Ext.state.Manager.clear(grid.stateId);
// Sort the store back to default
store.sort('first', 'ASC');
// Reconfigure the grid
grid.reconfigure(store, grid.self.prototype.columns);
```

Working example
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tp0
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tp1

Credits for the clear state:
https://druckit.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/ext-js-4-grid-state-management/

Comment: I was afraid it'd have to come to this.  Other than creating some base grid class and cloning the properties I need for state management, I think this is the easiest route.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your hands dirty and do it yourself using the self-reference of the config object.

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {

    saveConfigToMyself:function() {
        this.originalConfig = this;
        return this;
    },

  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  xtype: 'myGrid',
  viewModel: {
    type: 'myview'
  },
  title: 'Simpsons',
  stateful: true,
  multiSelect: true,
  stateId: 'stateGrid',
  closable: true,
  bind: {
    store: '{gridStore}'
  },
  columns: [{
    text: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    stateId: 'name'
  }, {
    text: 'Email',
    dataIndex: 'email',
    flex: 1,
    stateId: 'email'
  }, {
    text: 'Phone',
    dataIndex: 'phone',
    stateId: 'phone'
  }, {
    text: 'Date of Joining',
    dataIndex: 'doj',
    flex: 1,
    stateId: 'date'
  }]
}.saveConfigToMyself());
```

Please notice the **saveConfigToMyself()** declaration and also the call after the the config object.
Some attributes are lost during initialization (for example the "extend" attribute),to avoid that you could clone the config.

Check out this working fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tpo

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I think I would rather have some sort of base class that cloned the config in initComponent or something.

Comment: I overlooked that your problem was only targeting the grid.